# Cannot Drag and drop in jspx page

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using Oracle Jdeveloper 12c and I have JSPX page that I want to add UI component to it 
the problem is when I drag components into the page I cant drop it inside the page i.e. the drop is disabled.
Do anyone have an idea why this happening and how to solve this.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you drag the item into the structure pane window?
What if you right-click the top layout component in the structure page and choose to focus on that one.